# How to add custom date in order history comment in magento programmatically?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am updating/insert a new comment with custom date ,but comment are adding with current date and time not custom date,
Using this code

```
$new_date='2010-01-01';
$order->setData('created_at',$new_date);
$order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), 'This comment is programatically added', false);
$order->save();
```

how to add this custom date?Is there any way to achieve this..

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
$history = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status_history')
    ->setStatus($order->getStatus())
    ->setComment('My Comment!')
    ->setEntityName(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::HISTORY_ENTITY_NAME)
    ->setIsCustomerNotified(false)
    ->setCreatedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 60*60*24));

$order->addStatusHistory($history);
$order->save();
```

Please note that there is no need to calculate time zone offset when saving time in database. Magento expects time to be in UTC and already sets the default time zone with `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`,because of that we can use `time()` function. Magento will calculate time offset on the fly before displaying value on frontend/admin based on configuration found in `System > Configuration > General > Locale Options`

Comment: @Skeletor  Getting Error when I tried with this code as "Error Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db-name`.`sales_flat_order_status_history`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CE7C71E74CB74DDACED337CEE6753D5E` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_order` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON U), query was: INSERT INTO `sales_flat_order_status_history` (`comment`, `status`, `created_at`, `entity_name`) VALUES (?, ?, '2017-08-30 11:44:16', ?)"